# "Too many automatic redirects" error on webclient downloadfile?

Tags: c#, webclient

When coding a custom installer with C# WinForms I have stumbled upon the following error: "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

Too many automatic redirections were attempted.
"

It is accompanied by the following error text:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Net.WebException: Too many automatic redirections were attempted.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at Security__Installer.frmInstaller.Install()
   at Security__Installer.frmInstaller.btnNext_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I'm trying to make an installer for a mod I built for GTA V, and it is going to upon you clicking a button, run code to download a .rar file and a .zip file (other mods that mine is dependent on), If i have the zip and rar I have all the code I need to unzip/unrar, install them and my mod etc. But I don't want to steal another mod author's mod, I want to download it directly from them so that they get the download count for it. Am I missing something here?

I've tried going to the link that I'm providing it and it's all fine there, doesn't even appear to redirect which confuses me.

Some of my code:

```
webClient.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "security=true");
            webClient.DownloadFile("https://www.lcpdfr.com/files/file/22536-gruppe-sechs-corporate-security-agency/?do=download&csrfKey=a2526f8cfe74c1d9c23cc78f839d891c", dir + "\\temp\\GruppeSechs.rar");
```

I expect that the rar will appear and I will be able to unrar it but unfortunatley it simply waits for a while, displays the error, and no matter what I click it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter your address into Firefox, it'll load a page after a delay.  If you F12 and go to the Network tab, edit the request, strip out the headers and enter your Cookie: security=true, you'll see the 307 temporary redirect loop.

This might be something broken on the lcpdfr.com site or a mechanism to prevent 'stealing' their bandwidth with direct downloading or perhaps an incorrect request.

[image: repeated 307 in Firefox]